# How do I get the scope values of a discord oauth2 implicit grant?

Tags: javascript, html, oauth-2.0, discord.js

I have built a discord bot and now want to build a website for it. I have managed to setup an implicit grant with discord oauth2, however I don't know how to get any of my scope values (identity, email, guilds, bot). All I have is the access token, the token type, the time it will take to expire, the guild id and the scopes, which are listed in the url. Please help!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the [GetCurrentUser Api](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-current-user)

It is a GET to https://discord.com/api/users/@me

And you have to pass the Authorization header with your token.

[image]

### EDIT

In javascript this code should do the work:

```
fetch('https://discord.com/api/users/@me', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': jwtToken,
  }
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Or async version:

```
async getUserInfo() {
 const response = await fetch('https://discord.com/api/users/@me', {
   method: 'GET',
   headers: {
     'Authorization': jwtToken,
   }
 });
 var data = await response.json();
 console.log(data);
}

getUserInfo();
```

Comment: I think that might work, however how do you pass the Authorization Header with a token? Could you please add a code example for implementation? Yes, I have no idea about what I am doing.

Comment: And how do you integrate json and html?

Comment: With javascript you can just use fetch (or external libraries like axsios). Look at the edit

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The values you're looking for should be set as claims in your token.

Try to paste the token into https://jwt.io/

Comment: They are not set as claims, unless I am decoding it wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Adding to Antonio's answer:

You need to use "Bearer tokenvalue" as the value in your Authorization header

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34353085)

Comment: No! "Bearer" is not needed. Read the Discord API documentation